# push items to an array in a object using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to update the posts array in the data object. 
It dosent work here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Post = require('./post');
const Review = require('./comment')

    const User = mongoose.Schema({
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

        // necessary details needed for the user to initially working with
        data: {

            posts: [
                Post
            ],
            following: [String]
            }
        }

    });
```

I have already tried:

```
User.update({_id: user}, {data:{$push: {posts: post
  }}}).then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
  })
```

but it dosent work. Thank you.

Comment: Check the answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
User.update(
    { "_id": user },
    {
        "$push":
            {
                "data.posts": post
            }
    }
).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

[Read more about $push here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

***Hope this solves your query!***

Comment: It didn't push it to array. Got `{ok:0, n:0, nModified:0}`

Comment: Oops, I have just updated the answer. Try again now.

Comment: Update it works when I remove all the double qoutes and leave the later as { "data.posts": post }

Comment: Yes it works now thank you. I removed the double qoutes and it still works